# Sequelize migration fails by cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When trying to run my migration on Sequelize, I am getting the following error;

```
== 20170904085107-kognitio-queue: migrating =======
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at Object.attributeToSQL (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js:240:34)
    at Object.attributesToSQL (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js:306:45)
    at QueryInterface.createTable (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:171:38)
    at Object.up (/home/vagrant/insights-api/lib/migrations/20170904085107-kognitio-queue.js:4:31)
    at constructor._exec (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:104:23)
    at constructor.up (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js:69:17)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/umzug/index.js:124:28)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/finally.js:57:23)
    at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
    at Promise._resolveCallback (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:432:57)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/vagrant/insights-api/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:524:17)
```

The migration file is as follows;

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.createTable('Kognitio_Queue', {
            queue_id: {
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            queue_user: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.STRING(20)
            },
            queue_query: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.LONG
            },
            queue_added: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATETIME,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW
            },
            queue_executed: {
                allowNull: true,
                type: Sequelize.DATETIME
            },
            queue_save_results: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
            },
            queue_results_path: {
                allowNull: true,
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            }
        });
    },
    down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('Kognitio_Queue');
    }
};
```

And my model file for this is;

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Kognitio_Queue = sequelize.define('Kognitio_Queue', {
        queue_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        queue_user: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false
        },
        queue_query: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.LONG
        },
        queue_added: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.DATETIME
        },
        queue_executed: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.DATETIME
        },
        queue_save_results: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
        },
        queue_results_path: {
            allowNull: true,
            type: DataTypes.TEXT
        }
    }, {
        underscored: true,
        freezeTableName: true
    });
    return Kognitio_Queue;
};
```

I am at a loss as to what could be causing this error to occur as I have checked these files against other migrations that work successfully and can see no differences between them. I have gone as far as to clear out the entire database and remigrate, but this one is the only one that fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: If someone is still having this error even after conrrect data types, wrap your queryInteface call in a try catch and log the error. It will give you stack trace, that will provide more info

Answer (score 56):

Figured out it was unrecognised data types.

Comment: Uffff, error-catching in sequelize suck soooooo much

Comment: Can explain the error in a bit more detail.

Comment: In some cases, the error the type is missed. In my case: I wanted to update the allowNull property but I missed the type. I hope it solves your doubt.

Comment: I my case I missed type when I want to changeColumn then which I fixed by adding type but then I get this error again when I want to undo the previous migration I used to change gosh

Comment: my mistake was that I was trying to change the column to allow `null` but wasn't providing the type at all

Comment: same typo mistake wrote 'tepy' instead of 'type'. sequelize are not nice though

Comment: Same, where is the error stack!!

Answer (score 18):

Make sure to use uppercase datatypes:

use DATE instead of Date or date

Comment: Thanks! You saved me!

Answer (score 15):

Change **DATETIME** to **DATE**, there is no data type named DATETIME in sequelize. DATE works same as DATETIME, and DATEONLY works like DATE
Details: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html